# how to databind a datalist's page index to a button's commandname?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

i got this inside a button inside a datalist

```
CommandName="<%# Container.ItemIndex %>"
```

when i click the button, i'm expecting commandname to = 0, then 1, then 2, etc, as the datalist progresses, and i'm using that value in the button click's c#

but i'm getting this error, i'm pretty sure i'm using this exact setup on another page and i have no problems, any idea what's going on?

Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'ItemIndex'

Answer (score 0):

figured out this will work for some reason, posting for future searchers

```
CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"ItemIndex")  %>'
```